# Combining Tkinter and SSHFS in order to use tkFileDialog on remote server

Tags: python, tkinter, sshfs

I would like to provide a simple GUI for selecting files on the remote server for my application. The Tkinter widgets do not support this inherently, so I am looking for some workarounds. My local machine is a Mac, and the remote machine is CentOS 6.9.

The type of process I need is this: user selects a remote file. A python script is used to extract information from this file, and writes this to a new file in the same directory.

A much simpler thing would perhaps be for the user to provide the filename via a `filename = input("Path to file: ")`, but that requires the user to get the path from the remote server first. Ideally I would like the application to be self-consistent.

Could the SSHFS be used in combination with the `tkFileDialog` module? The user would walk the mounted file system, select the file, actions would be performed, and the new file would be stored in the mounted file system and automatically transferred to the remote system. Possible?

Or, crazy idea: I would recreate the remote `$HOME` file structure locally, but just creating a temporary directory and a bunch of correctly named empty files. The user can walk this "fake" file system, select the file of interest, and then the application can use this path to retrieve the file, perform the actions, and send back the new file... Okay, perhaps not the most elegant solution....

Comment: what system do you use - Windows, Linux, Mac ? On Linux Mint I can use standard file manager - `Caja/Nemo/Nautilus` - and using address `sftp://user@domain.com` I can see remote folders and file (on server which use `ssh`) like local files. Probably it is mounted in some folder and I could use any tool to work with remote files but I did't try tkFileDialog.

Comment: My local machine is a Mac, the remote is CentOS.

Comment: I tested and it mouted my Raspberry Pi computer (with Debian) as folder `/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=raspberry,user=pi/` and I can choose file with `askopenfilename` and it can read it with standard `open()` and `read()`. But I don't know if it uses `sshfs` or rather `gvfs`

Comment: Could you provide a simple code example? The documentation on SSHFS is a bit lacking in useful examples.

Comment: I can't I used file manager with path `sftp://pi@raspberry` and it automatically mounted it. I don't have to mount it manually.

Comment: Using Google I found some tutorials for `sshfs`: ie. [Mount a remote SSH folder in Ubuntu (cmd and GUI)](http://howto.blbosti.com/2010/09/mount-a-remote-ssh-folder-in-ubuntu-cmd-and-gui/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested `sshfs` on notebook (`Linux Mint`) to access remote folder on Raspberry Pi (`Raspbian` based on `Debian`) and it can mount remote folder as local folder and then I can use Python and other programs to work with remote files.

To mount it:

```
mkdir local_pi
sshfs pi@192.168.1.100:/home/pi/ local_pi

# here ask for password of user `pi`
```

It mounts remote folder `/home/pi/` as local folder `local_pi` and it block access to `/home/` so it can restrict access only to some folder and its subfolders.

---

I tested in Python and it worked:

- `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` to select file
- standard `open()`, `read()`, `write()` to read and write file
- `os.makedirs(dirname)` to create folder
- `os.listdir(dirname)` to get filenames in folder

Comment: is all the remote content downloaded to the local machine?

Comment: not, it keeps open ssh connection all the time and when you `read()` file then it has to get it from server, and when you `write()` then it sends it on server.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on my system as well. This is very cool!